# Prevent multiple Ionic Alerts from stacking up

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How can I detect if ionic 2 [alert ui component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#alert) instance is already open in order not to present another alert ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up writing a wrapping provider for Ionic's Alert controller like so :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class Alert {
  public alertPresented: any;
  constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.alertPresented = false
  }

  present(title, subTitle) {
    let vm = this
    if(!vm.alertPresented) {
      vm.alertPresented = true
      vm.alertCtrl.create({
        title: title,
        subTitle: subTitle,
        buttons: [{
          text: 'OK',
          handler: () => {
            vm.alertPresented = false
          }
        }],
      }).present();
    }
  }
}
```

where `alertPresented` flag prevents more than one instance from being presented

Comment: This would only block a new alert from being created. This would not auto-dismiss the old alert and present the latest one, right?

Comment: Any idea on how to auto dismiss an old alert and present the new one?

Comment: I've created a question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45919152/dismiss-old-alert-and-present-latest-alert-ionic3

Answer (score 2):

I have another idea that you can assign message for a variable and check new message is equal to it or not. If equal, return. 
This is my code and hope you enjoy with it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class AlertProvider {

  public showingMessage = ""

  constructor(
    private alertController: AlertController
  ) {}

  showAlert(message) {
    // Check this message is showing or not
    if (message === this.showingMessage) {
      return
    }

    this.showingMessage = message
    this.alertController.create({
      title: "APP_NAME",
      message: message,
      buttons: [{
        text: "OK",
        handler: () => {
          this.showingMessage = ""
        }
      }]
    }).present()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `AlertService` to handle that with more options without inject an event for the buttons

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, Alert } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * A simple alert class to show only one alert at the same time
 */
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
  currentAlert: Alert
  constructor(private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  show(title, message, buttons: any = [], inputs: any = [], cssClass = '') {
    if (!buttons.length) {
      buttons.push('Ok')
    }
    let alertOptions: any = {
      title: title,
      subTitle: message,
      buttons: buttons,
      cssClass: buttons.length === 2 ? 'confirmAlert' : cssClass
    }
    if (inputs.length) {
      alertOptions.inputs = inputs
    }
    if (!this.currentAlert) {
      this.currentAlert = this.alertCtrl.create(alertOptions)
      this.currentAlert.present()
      this.currentAlert.onDidDismiss(() => {
        this.currentAlert = null
      })
    }
    return this.currentAlert
  }
}
```

Regards, Nicholls

Answer (score 0):

**My solution worked, i had to put a boolean and set it true after a cancel event and set it false when an alert is presented**

```
if (this.network_alert) {
      let alert = await this.alertController.create({
        header: "No Network",
        message:
          "Please check your internet connection",
        buttons: [{
          text: "Dismiss",
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
            this.network_alert = true
          }
        }],

      });
      await alert.present();
      this.network_alert = false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please insert your comment into your answer, or add context to your code, and explain what it does. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to see what I mean.